# Onscroll navbar not working properly. In mobile device when clicked on hamburger menu it will goes upward

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```
<nav id="mynav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top">
        <div id="mainnav" class="container-fluid" >
                <a class="navbar-brand pt-0 pb-0" href="index.html">
                    <img src="./assets/pranav logo1 (1).png" class="img-fluid d-inline-block align-top logo" alt="" loading="lazy">
                </a>
    
                <button class="navbar-toggler mr-5" id="mynavbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mob" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="services.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Services
                      </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" href="services.html">Web Designing</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" href="services.html">Software Development</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" href="services.html">Digital Marketing</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="contact-us.html">Contact</a>
                      </li>
    
    
                  </ul>
                </div>
              
           
        </div>
        </nav> 


$(document).ready(function(){
    var backScroll =window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function (){
        var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
        if(backScroll >currentScroll) {
            document.getElementById("mynav").style.top="0";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("mynav").style.top="-100px";

        }
        backScroll = currentScroll;
    }
    
});
```

[(Wrong Output)The navbar is hidden (top:-100px)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1wL.jpg)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpurB.jpg)

On desktop code works properly when downward scroll is detected navbar is hidden (top:100px) and when upward scroll is detected navbar will be display but In mobile device When I clicked on hamburger menu it collapse but also hiding logo and hamberger section.
I uploaded please you will get it.

Comment: Where is your css?

Comment: bootstrap based design#mynav{
    top: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}